# 基本設定>ニュースレターに英語がある

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 英語

`基本設定`に英語があります。
**URL**
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/
**英語の部分**

> Sign up for a weekly email with top questions and answers, important announcements and unanswered questions (see an example newsletter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

前に訳したときと原文が変わってない気がしますが、訳が飛んでいるんですね・・・。

> ニュースレターでは人気の質問や回答、まだ回答されていない質問、その他の重要なお知らせを毎週配信しています。[サンプルはこちら](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters/newsletter?site=ja.stackoverflow.com)。

としてみます。

Comment: それがいいと思います。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 反映されていますね。ありがとうございました。